# Space added at end of each item parsed from comma-delimited list: how to avoid this?

Tags: spacing, comma-separated-list

I am building a package for typesetting Celtic music tunebooks.  One feature I make available is the command `\altnames`, which takes a comma-delimited list of alternate tune names as an argument.  Below is an MWE of the `\altnames` command presented in a single document file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{loopitemcounter}\setcounter{loopitemcounter}{0}

\def\listingloopENDMARKER{\listingloopENDMARKER}

\long\def\listingloop#1in#2#3{%
   \looppicker{#1}{#3}#2,\listingloopENDMARKER,%
}

\long\def\looppicker#1#2#3,{%
   \def\tempitem{#3}%
   %\ifx\tempitem\listingloopENDMARKER
   \ifx\listingloopENDMARKER\tempitem %
      \let\next=\relax%
   \else %
      \def#1{#3}%
      \ifnum\value{loopitemcounter}=0
         #2%
      \else %
         ,\space#2%
      \fi
      \def\next{\looppicker{#1}{#2}}%
   \fi
   \stepcounter{loopitemcounter}
   \next
}

\newcommand{\altnames}[1]{%
   \listingloop\@picked@name in{#1}{%
      \textit\@picked@name
   }
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\altnames{The Day After,Trump? Really?,The End Days}
\end{document}
```

The `\looppicker` command prints each tune name parsed from the list, following each by a comma and a space (except for the last one).  The result I am getting is the following:
[image: Result of MWE above, showing spaces after tune neames]

The comma and space added between names by `\looppicker` is as intended, but as you can see an extra space is added immediately after each name, *before* the comma.  How can I avoid this?

The `\listingloop\@picked@name in{#1}{%` line in `\altnames`, I thought, was the source, specifically the space before the word "in."  This made sense (to me), as the "in" is the delimiter, and everything before it--including the space--becomes #1 in the `\listingloop` command.  As you would expect, simply removing the space wreaks havoc.  I tried using `_in_` as the delimiter instead, but I get the same result.  So, now I am thinking the `\listingloop\@picked@name in{#1}{%` line is **not** the culprit.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.  This one has me stumped, and I suspect there is something deeper and more subtle going on with how TeX macro definitions and their arguments are parsed, and I simply don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `%` after `\stepcounter{loopitemcounter}` in the definition of `\looppicker`:

```
\long\def\looppicker#1#2#3,{%
   \def\tempitem{#3}%
   %\ifx\tempitem\listingloopENDMARKER
   \ifx\listingloopENDMARKER\tempitem %
      \let\next=\relax%
   \else %
      \def#1{#3}%
      \ifnum\value{loopitemcounter}=0
         #2%
      \else %
         ,\space#2%
      \fi
      \def\next{\looppicker{#1}{#2}}%
   \fi
   \stepcounter{loopitemcounter}% <- here
   \next
}
```

Comment: Well, didn't see that coming.  Thank you sooo much.  Might I ask why putting that `%` there makes a difference?  I thought I had a handle on the % sign thing, but apparently not.

Comment: @celticflute -- Why did you think it didn't add a space? You seem to be using `%` even in places where the `%` sign won't make a difference. (Not meant as a criticism: there are editor-specific reasons why I add `%` to line ends even though they make no difference to *TeX.)

Comment: @jon -- (Sigh.  Nothing for it ...) I guess I really have no clue about when a `%` sign is needed and when it isn't.  Is there any definitive discussion of this subject to which you can point me?  (Maybe it is time to get the TexBook.)